# Finding the minimum date for matching record in another data frame

Tags: r, date, datetime, if-statement, for-loop

I have a dataset of hospital encounters like so:

```
  VISIT_KEY PAT_KEY DICT_ENC_TYPE_KEY     HOSP_DISCHRG_DT MED_ORD_ID HAD_FOLLOWUP
1  82919395 8979499                83 2014-09-07 10:47:00   58826846            1
2  82919395 8979499                83 2014-09-07 10:47:00   58826847            1
3  82919395 8979499                83 2014-09-07 10:47:00   58826848            1
4  82919395 8979499                83 2014-09-07 10:47:00   58826845            1
5  77312433 8979499                83 2015-02-01 09:33:00   98525833            1
6  77312433 8979499                83 2015-02-01 09:33:00   98525834            1
7  77312433 8979499                83 2015-02-01 09:33:00   98525835            1
```

and a data set of follow-up encounters like so:

```
  VISIT_KEY PAT_KEY DICT_ENC_TYPE_KEY     APPT_CHECKIN_DT
1  84273751 8979499               108 2015-02-07 11:57:46
2  83999897 8979499               108 2014-09-13 16:51:22
3  83881023 8979499               108 2014-11-12 10:37:51
4  83999896 8979499               108 2014-11-20 09:23:25
5  95164335 8979499               108 2016-07-27 15:30:25
6  83922326 8979499               108 2014-11-16 09:08:47
```

I am trying to get the minimum value of the APP_CHECKIN_DT for an encounter into a new field for the hospital encounter dataset, **FOLLOWUP_DT**. This would need to be the minimum APP_CHECKIN_DT that is also greater than the HOSP_DISCHRG_DT.

For example:

- For VISIT_KEY = 82919395, the earliest APP_CHECKIN_DT in the second dataset that is greater than the HOSP_DISCHRG_DT of 2014-09-07 10:47:00 for this patient would be 2014-09-13 16:51:22
- For VISIT_KEY = 77312433, the earliest APP_CHECKIN_DT in the second dataset that is greater than the HOSP_DISCHRG_DT of 2015-02-01 09:33:00 for this patient would be 2015-02-07 11:57:46

The final hospital encounter dataset would look like:

```
  VISIT_KEY PAT_KEY DICT_ENC_TYPE_KEY     HOSP_DISCHRG_DT MED_ORD_ID HAD_FOLLOWUP         FOLLOWUP_DT
1  82919395 8979499                83 2014-09-07 10:47:00   58826846            1 2014-09-13 16:51:22
2  82919395 8979499                83 2014-09-07 10:47:00   58826847            1 2014-09-13 16:51:22
3  82919395 8979499                83 2014-09-07 10:47:00   58826848            1 2014-09-13 16:51:22
4  82919395 8979499                83 2014-09-07 10:47:00   58826845            1 2014-09-13 16:51:22
5  77312433 8979499                83 2015-02-01 09:33:00   98525833            1 2015-02-07 11:57:46
6  77312433 8979499                83 2015-02-01 09:33:00   98525834            1 2015-02-07 11:57:46
7  77312433 8979499                83 2015-02-01 09:33:00   98525835            1 2015-02-07 11:57:46
```

I tried some FOR loops with ifelse statements like below in order to find see if the encounter had a followup, then get the APPT_CHECKIN_DT see if the hospital encounter PAT_KEY matches the outpatient encounter PAT_KEY and the APPT_CHECKIN_DT is greater than the HOSP_DISCHRG_DT, and then take the minimum APPT_CHECKIN_DT to get the followup date:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(children_dx)) {
  children_dx$FOLLOW_UP_DATE[i] <- 
    ifelse(children_dx$HAD_FOLLOWUP[i] == 1,
           ifelse(outpatient_visits$APPT_CHECKIN_DT[children_dx$PAT_KEY[i] == outpatient_visits$PAT_KEY] > children_dx$HOSP_DISCHRG_DT[i],
                  as.character(min(outpatient_visits$APPT_CHECKIN_DT[children_dx$PAT_KEY[i] == outpatient_visits$PAT_KEY])),
                  NA),NA)
}
```

However, this takes very long to run for the full dataset, and even when completed, the FOLLOWUP_DATE is the overall minimum value for APPT_CHECKIN_DT for the whole dataset, not just the records where PAT_KEY matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a `merge` with *subset* then `aggregate` with *min* then `merge` on original df:

**Data**

```
setClass('myDate')
setAs('character', 'myDate', function(from) as.POSIXct(from, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

hospital_encounters <- read.table(text="
            VISIT_KEY PAT_KEY DICT_ENC_TYPE_KEY     HOSP_DISCHRG_DT MED_ORD_ID HAD_FOLLOWUP
            1  82919395 8979499                83 '2014-09-07 10:47:00'   58826846            1
            2  82919395 8979499                83 '2014-09-07 10:47:00'   58826847            1
            3  82919395 8979499                83 '2014-09-07 10:47:00'   58826848            1
            4  82919395 8979499                83 '2014-09-07 10:47:00'   58826845            1
            5  77312433 8979499                83 '2015-02-01 09:33:00'   98525833            1
            6  77312433 8979499                83 '2015-02-01 09:33:00'   98525834            1
            7  77312433 8979499                83 '2015-02-01 09:33:00'   98525835            1", 
            header=TRUE, colClasses = c('numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric', 'myDate', 'numeric', 'numeric'),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)    

follow_up_encounters <- read.table(text="  VISIT_KEY PAT_KEY DICT_ENC_TYPE_KEY     APPT_CHECKIN_DT
            1  84273751 8979499               108 '2015-02-07 11:57:46'
            2  83999897 8979499               108 '2014-09-13 16:51:22'
            3  83881023 8979499               108 '2014-11-12 10:37:51'
            4  83999896 8979499               108 '2014-11-20 09:23:25'
            5  95164335 8979499               108 '2016-07-27 15:30:25'
            6  83922326 8979499               108 '2014-11-16 09:08:47'",
            header=TRUE, colClasses = c('numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric', 'myDate'),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Process**

```
mdf <- subset(merge(hospital_encounters, follow_up_encounters[c("PAT_KEY", "APPT_CHECKIN_DT")], 
              by=c("PAT_KEY")), APPT_CHECKIN_DT > HOSP_DISCHRG_DT)

aggdf <- setNames(aggregate(APPT_CHECKIN_DT~ PAT_KEY + VISIT_KEY, mdf, FUN=min),
                  c("PAT_KEY", "VISIT_KEY", "FOLLOWUP_DT"))

hospital_encounters <- merge(hospital_encounters, aggdf, c("PAT_KEY", "VISIT_KEY"))
```

**Output**

```
hospital_encounters

#   PAT_KEY VISIT_KEY DICT_ENC_TYPE_KEY     HOSP_DISCHRG_DT MED_ORD_ID HAD_FOLLOWUP         FOLLOWUP_DT
# 1 8979499  77312433                83 2015-02-01 09:33:00   98525833            1 2015-02-07 11:57:46
# 2 8979499  77312433                83 2015-02-01 09:33:00   98525834            1 2015-02-07 11:57:46
# 3 8979499  77312433                83 2015-02-01 09:33:00   98525835            1 2015-02-07 11:57:46
# 4 8979499  82919395                83 2014-09-07 10:47:00   58826846            1 2014-09-13 16:51:22
# 5 8979499  82919395                83 2014-09-07 10:47:00   58826847            1 2014-09-13 16:51:22
# 6 8979499  82919395                83 2014-09-07 10:47:00   58826848            1 2014-09-13 16:51:22
# 7 8979499  82919395                83 2014-09-07 10:47:00   58826845            1 2014-09-13 16:51:22
```

Comment: This looks like its working, but I keep recieveing this error: `Error in min.default(c(1420043124, 1420043124, 1420043124, 1420043124,  : 
  invalid 'type' (list) of argument` when trying to get the minimum

Comment: In your actual data frame, are the dates actual dates, character, factor? Try converting to POSIXct type. If you run the data sample in this solution and code, you see solution works.

Answer (score 0):

this question is probably easier and faster to solve using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

#read in the data, convert to data.table using setDT, convert the datetime column into POSIX format, set up a joining key
dt1 <- setDT(read.table(text="VISIT_KEY PAT_KEY DICT_ENC_TYPE_KEY     HOSP_DISCHRG_DT MED_ORD_ID HAD_FOLLOWUP
82919395 8979499                83 '2014-09-07 10:47:00'   58826846            1
82919395 8979499                83 '2014-09-07 10:47:00'   58826847            1
82919395 8979499                83 '2014-09-07 10:47:00'   58826848            1
82919395 8979499                83 '2014-09-07 10:47:00'   58826845            1
77312433 8979499                83 '2015-02-01 09:33:00'   98525833            1
77312433 8979499                83 '2015-02-01 09:33:00'   98525834            1
77312433 8979499                83 '2015-02-01 09:33:00'   98525835            1", header=TRUE))[,
    HOSP_DISCHRG_DT:=strptime(HOSP_DISCHRG_DT, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")][,
        KEY_DATE:=HOSP_DISCHRG_DT]

dt2 <- setDT(read.table(text="VISIT_KEY PAT_KEY DICT_ENC_TYPE_KEY APPT_CHECKIN_DT
84273751 8979499               108 '2015-02-07 11:57:46'
83999897 8979499               108 '2014-09-13 16:51:22'
83881023 8979499               108 '2014-11-12 10:37:51'
83999896 8979499               108 '2014-11-20 09:23:25'
95164335 8979499               108 '2016-07-27 15:30:25'
83922326 8979499               108 '2014-11-16 09:08:47'", header=TRUE))[,
    APPT_CHECKIN_DT:=strptime(APPT_CHECKIN_DT, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")][,
        list(APPT_CHECKIN_DT, KEY_DATE=APPT_CHECKIN_DT)]

#do check out ?data.table to understand the meaning of roll
dt2[dt1, on="KEY_DATE", roll=-Inf][, 
    KEY_DATE:=NULL]    #remove the joining key
```